# How do you identify a list of filepaths containing non-ascii characters?

Tags: python, path, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I would like to print a list of file paths from a Windows directory which contain non-ascii characters.  The files are located on deeply-nested subdirectories.

I have two pieces of the problem figured out:

1. A conditional that can evaluate a character and determine it's unicode code.  Unicode codes greater than 128 are non-ascii characters:

```
if ord(i) > 128
```

2. A script that can extract file paths from a directory recursively:

```
directory = "C:\Temp"

[print(os.path.join(dp, f)) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(directory) for f in filenames]
```

I have tried to combine these two pieces of information in various ways:

```
[print(os.path.join(dp, f)) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(directory) for f in filenames if ord(f) < 128]
```

This doesn't work because the input into `ord` is the filepath, not an individual character.  So I've tried various ways of changing f into a list of strings:

1. List comprehension

```
[print(os.path.join(dp, f)) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(directory) for f in filenames if ord([x for x in list(f)] < 128)]
```

> Error code: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

2. Unpacking

```
[print(os.path.join(dp, f)) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(directory) for f in filenames if ord([x for x in (*f)] < 128)]
```

> Error code: SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here`

3. Adding a clause to the list comprehension:

```
[print(os.path.join(dp, f)) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(directory) for x in f in filenames if ord(x < 128)]
```

> Error code: NameError: name 'f' is not defined`

In case it's helpful, this piece of code works - it removes non-ascii characters from filepaths in the directory.  I just want to have a list of the files it changes for my own sense of control over the process

```
def remove_non_ascii_1(text):

    return ''.join(i for i in text if ord(i) < 128)

[os.rename(os.path.join(dp, f), remove_non_ascii_1(os.path.join(dp, f))) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(directory) for f in filenames]
```

Comment: `print` shouldn't have any trouble printing any Unicode characters if you have your console interface set properly.

Comment: I'm trying to identify the non-ascii characters because they give me trouble in a later stage in the project when I use os.rename to move the files into new folders

Comment: Printing is the least of your trouble then.

Comment: changed the question title to make it more clear that it's not the printing that's important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def is_ascii_filename(fn):
    return all(ord(ch) < 128 for ch in fn)
```

Comment: Youre awesome Mark Ransom!  Here's the code in full: `[print(os.path.join(dp, f)) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(directory) for f in filenames if not is_ascii_filename(f)]`

Comment: @oymonk one of the things I love about Python is how easy it is to break a problem into smaller easily solved pieces.